# A way to filter by columns that contain a value that is in a list with separators

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I have a data format that looks like this:

```
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Value = c("val1; val2; val3", "val1", "val2", "val20; val3", "val2; val3")
df = data.frame(ID, Value)
```

I want to apply a filter that will return only rows with val2 in them (not, e.g., val20). The only thing I've been able to think of is:

```
dplyr::filter(df, 'val2' %in% unlist(strsplit(as.character(Value), ";")))
```

This does nothing. It returns the entire row. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries with `grepl`/`str_detect` :

```
subset(df, grepl('\\bval2\\b', Value))

#  ID            Value
#1  1 val1; val2; val3
#3  3             val2
#5  5       val2; val3
```

With `dplyr::filter` :

```
dplyr::filter(df, grepl('\\bval2\\b', Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep`

```
df1[grep("\\bval2\\b', df$Value),]
```